# Ruby strings index do not behave the same

Tags: ruby

I parse the below line

```
        &lt;em&gt;&lt;/em&gt;">Markov, Andrei</a>
```

And as per the below output, the index don't behave the same all the time

```
Markov, Andrei
Markov, Andrei</a>
```

Here is my code

```
line_list.each do |line|
    if line.include? name
        start = line.index('>') + 1
        finish = line.index('<', start) - 1
        elem = line[start,finish]

        puts line
        for i in(start..finish)
            print line[i]
        end
        puts
        puts elem
        puts
    end
end
```

Comment: This site encourages people to check official documentations first (i.e. Ruby docs) before posting a question here at StackOverflow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
for i in(start..finish)
    print line[i]
end
```

You're going from index `start` to `finish`. When you say this:

```
elem = line[start,finish]
```

You're starting at index `start` and then getting `finish` characters, not going to index `finish`.

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001128):

> If passed a single `Fixnum`, returns a substring of one character at that position. If passed two `Fixnum` objects, returns a substring starting at the offset given by the first, and a length given by the second.

Comment: The answer is: line[start..finish]

Comment: @DjAlan: I thought the question was "why are `line[start,finish]` and `for i in(start..finish);print line[i];end` producing different results.

Answer (score -2):

You should use regular expressions instead !
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html

**UPDATE** here is the code

```
line_list.each do |line|
    elem = line.match(/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/)[1]
end
```

Comment: Please explain why he should use regex?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel and write a dozen lines of questionnable code in order to extract a pattern from a string, which is easily done in one cleaner, faster, easier to maintain line with regexp ?

The moral of the story is: don't ever try to educate the guy who asks the question, you will be downvoted.

Comment: The moral of the story is, provide a rationale for the recommendation and some sample code, rather than throw out a simple statement and a link.